# Gap between title and fragment in Bottom Navigation Activity template

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I was checking out the Android Studio's `Bottom Navigation Activity` project template, and found that that is a gap between the 'title' and 'home fragment'. The only change I added was a `android:background="@color/colorAccent"` to the `fragment_home.xml` to highlight the gap?

Is there any use of this gap? How to get rid of this gap?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the cause. It is due to the `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` found in 'activity_main.xml'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"

  android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

  >
```